# Sort and filter dataframe by group count

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I want to sort/filter based on a group count. For example, I want to get the top 2 `Symbols` per `Date`.

```
   Name     Date Symbol
0  Ajay  2018_Q1     AA
1  Ajay  2018_Q1     BB
2  Ajay  2019_Q1     AA
3  Ajay  2018_Q1     DD
4  Ajay  2019_Q1     AA
5  Faye  2019_Q1     DD
6   Jay  2019_Q1     DD
7  Faye  2019_Q1     ZZ
8  Faye  2018_Q1     AA
9   Ray  2018_Q1     BB
```

So the output dataframe should look like this:

```
   Count     Date Symbol
0      2  2018_Q1     AA
1      2  2018_Q1     BB
2      2  2019_Q1     AA
3      2  2019_Q1     DD
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66194693/how-to-get-top-5-reason-for-each-airline/66195291#66195291

Comment: Look at groupby `df['col1','col2','col3','col4'].groupby(['col1','col2']).count()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get top 5 reason for each airline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66194693/how-to-get-top-5-reason-for-each-airline)

Comment: It does except the `top_n` doesn't seem to have any bearing on the result

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(['Date', 'Symbol']).size().reset_index(name='RowCount')
```

for filtering top N

```
df = df.groupby(['Date', 'Symbol'])['count'].nlargest(2).reset_index()
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html

Comment: This will not return `Date` and `Symbol`

Comment: This results in: `KeyError: 'Column not found: count'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> (df.groupby(['Symbol', 'Date'])['Name']
       .size().groupby(level=1, group_keys=False)
       .nlargest(2).reset_index(name='count')
    )
  Symbol     Date  count
0     AA  2018_Q1      2
1     BB  2018_Q1      2
2     AA  2019_Q1      2
3     DD  2019_Q1      2
```